# Node.js alternative to PHP's exec

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, express

I want to write a piece of `C` software (like prime number factorization) and place it on my web-server (based on `Node.js`).
Then I would like to have an `HTML`-document with a form and a button.

When the button is clicked the `C`-program should be executed (on the server) with the a text-field of the form passed as input parameter. The 
output of the `C`-program should be passed to an `HTML`-textfield again.

In `PHP` something like this is possible:

```
<?php
exec('~/tools/myprog.o');
?>
```

How would I go about something like this in `Node.js` (`Express.js` is fine as well). Especially the input/output redirection?

Comment: use [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that your question is 2 part.

1. PHP's exec equivalent for node.js
2. Execute C program and provide its out put using node.js.

Sticking to pure node.js, you would be able to execute and get access to stdout and stderr with following code.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("ls -l", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(error || stdout || stderr);
});
```

For #2,
    I am not sure if you could directly execute a "c" program, so I guess you'd need to do something like this

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("gcc ~/tools/myprog.c -o prime && ./prime", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(error || stdout || stderr);
});
```

Above code is definitely not thread safe and if concurrent requests are made, it will break, Ideally you'd not compile it for every request, you'd compile and cache for first request (you can match time stamp of source and compiled output, if compiled output is absent or its time stamp is less - earlier then the source code then you need to compile it) and then use cached output on subsequent requests.

In express you can do something like below

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
router.get('/prime/:num',function(req, res, next){
   exec("gcc ~/tools/myprog.c -o prime && ./prime " + req.params.num, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      if(error){
         res.status(400).json({'message': error.message});
         return;
      }
      if(stderr){
         res.status(400).json({'message': stderr});
         return;
      }

      res.status(200).json({'result': stdout});
   });
});
```

You can play with above code snippets and get what you are looking for.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Why not just compile the C program in the application's .js entry file. That way you could prevent the app from booting if the compilation threw an error? You could even cache the program meta using `app.set('c-program-verson', 'here')` for later validation. In any event, it's probably not a good idea to compile a program during application lifecycle. This should most definitely be done in your deploy (or build process if you're transpiling JS) process. You could leverage `npm postinstall` or `npm prestart` if using npm scripts.

Comment: @Seth I agree with you, in question he is trying to execute a c program directly, so I just mentioned that you won't be able to directly execute c program, you'd need to compile it. So In my response I have just showed a way how to compile from within node.js, you can implement it in gulp / grunt task so as on build code gets compiled into a folder and the it directly executes in request. My snippets are "just to provide an idea" what will need to be done in order to get desired output.

Comment: Thank you, so much. I actually meant an already compiled `C`program (executable) and just had a typo in my question. This seems like a solid answer. Accepted!